# How can I rig a cube in Blender so that it bends and twists?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

How to rig a cube so that the corners of the cube can twist and bend?

It will hopefully have a face too.

Comment: @Amir You are adding tags which relate to a possible answer as opposed to the question. Rigging in this context does not solely mean 'armatures and bones' (even if the only answer at the minute *does* relate to armatures and bones).

Comment: @RayMairlot Why do you view this as wrong? I think the tags are somewhat relavant, are they not?

Comment: @MartinZ These tags are unnecessarily restrictive. 'Rigging' could be done with curves, shapekeys, lattices, hooks and any number of other modifiers. Looking at the tags now, people may think that only answers related to bones and armatures are wanted, despite the original author never specifiying this.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, Here are the simple steps.

Create a Simple Cube and Subdivide it twice. (<kbd>A</kbd>*> Select all*, <kbd>W</kbd>*> Subdivide*)
[image]

Scale it 2 times (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>)
and Add a Single Bone (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Armature > Single Bone*).
Rename it to Root in (*3D view > Properties region (<kbd>N</kbd>)> Item*).
[image]
In edit Mode add 8 child bones (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) to root with tips facing the corners of the cube.
Turn on snapping (hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) to precisely move them to corners. Create one bone first, snap and place at a corner, then simply duplicate (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) and rotate (<kbd>R</kbd>). Don't forget to select rootbone as parent before duplicating.
[image]
In object mode, parent your cube object to the armature (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>). You are ready to animate. All corners work. Add more subdivisions for fine movement.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by select rootbone as parent? I am not sure how you are doing this. Please tell me

Comment: When in edit armature/bone mode, Look into the properties. you'll see a bone Icon. In that tab , look for relations >> Parent. In this drop down, you can select a bone as parent. usually , its the first bone (it becomes parent automatically, if we extrude the 2nd bones from first. but in my example i duplicated the bones, and then parent them to the first Bone.

Comment: Thanks. Which bone will I be duplicating? Because when I do it it is not connected.....

Comment: actually, i made a single bone. Then duplicate it. pointed its tip to one corner. Parented it to the first one (i named it root). then it was simply a matter of duplicating and rotating the new bones to match corners.
My bones are disconnected childs.